# How to use attribute as property value in SCSS

Tags: css, variables, sass, colors, scss-mixins

I'm trying to create a dynamic solution for colors in SCSS

The idea is use an attribute value in markup as property value in SCSS.

The example of the idea:

```
<p text-color="#00ff6e"> Sample </p>
```

And in SCSS

```
[text-color="$color"] {
  color: $color !important;
}
```

Is this even possible ? Do you ever try to build something like this ? 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

you don't even need SCSS - do it with [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)!

```css
p {
  color: var(--text-color) !important;
}
```

```html
<p style="
  --text-color: #00ff6e;
"> Sample </p>
```

note that even though custom properties have [wide support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) in evergreen browsers, internet explorer's support is entirely lacking at the moment (edge has full support starting version 16).

you may be tempted to attempt the [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function, but it'll fail in this case; its value is always treated as a CSS string.
furthermore, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*), it only has strong support within the `content` property, and while the `attribute-name` parameter has consistent behavior, support for `<type-or-unit>` is sparse.

Comment: Can I use this without a style attribute ? This probably will mess with SEO

Comment: Terrible support in IE :( Don't do this

Comment: @David - that is never a reason not to use something :) 

thanx for the heads up though

Comment: Interestingly, YouTube uses this method. Then has a separate style sheet for internet exploder :-)

Comment: *exploder*, lol! thanx for the feedback, @David, i added a note on browser support.

Answer (score 0):

I'd never have a reason to do this, especially if I can add a reusable class that sets:

```
.text-color {
  color: $color;
}
```

Comment: the reason could be to avoid clutter when specifying *every* desired color as a class. the OP wants the ability to specify colors from the markup side (to my understanding)